# Sql server: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1 when executing stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I give an error when executing a stored procedure using dynamic sql
this is my stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_InsertMagasinsInTable]
    (
    @Code varchar(15),
    @Surface int,
    @Lieu varchar(80),
    @Adresse varchar(150),
    @CodePostal varchar(10),
    @IDTCommune int,    
    @IDTPays int,
    @Ville varchar(80),
    @IdEnseigne int,
    @LibMagasin varchar(50),
    @TelStandard varchar(30),
    @IdClient int,
    @DateCreation datetime ,
    @AcrCreateur char(6)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CMD as varchar(1000)

SET @CMD='INSERT INTO MAG_Magasin
           (MAG_Magasin.NumMag
           , MAG_Magasin.Surface
           , MAG_Magasin.Lieu
           , MAG_Magasin.Adresse
           , MAG_Magasin.CodePostal
           , MAG_Magasin.IDTCommune
           , MAG_Magasin.IDTPays
           , MAG_Magasin.Ville
           , MAG_Magasin.IdEnseigne
           , MAG_Magasin.LibMagasin
           , MAG_Magasin.TelStandard
           , MAG_Magasin.IdClient
           , MAG_Magasin.DateCreation
           , MAG_Magasin.AcrCreateur)
       VALUES ('''+
            @Code + ''',' +
            CAST(@Surface AS VARCHAR) + ','''+
            @Lieu + ''','''+
            @Adresse + ''','''+
            @CodePostal + ''','''+              
            CAST(@IDTCommune AS VARCHAR) + ','+
            CAST(@IDTPays AS VARCHAR) + ','+
            @Ville + ''','+
            CAST(@IdEnseigne AS VARCHAR) + ','''+
            @LibMagasin + ''','''+
            @TelStandard + ''','+
            CAST(@IdClient AS VARCHAR) + ','+
            CAST(@DateCreation AS VARCHAR) + ''','''+
            @AcrCreateur +
            ')'                 

EXEC(@CMD)

END

EXEC SP_InsertMagasinsInTable   
    @Code = '234',
    @Surface = 245,
    @Lieu = 'Lieu',
    @Adresse ='Adresse',
    @CodePostal =  '78120',
    @IDTCommune = 45,   
    @IDTPays = 33,
    @Ville = 'Ville',
    @IdEnseigne = 42,
    @LibMagasin = 'LibMagasin',
    @TelStandard = '0123456789',
    @IdClient = 452,
    @DateCreation = '15:08:03',
    @AcrCreateur ='acr'
```

This is my error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 16
>   Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Comment: Can you `PRINT @CMD` without executing it? You're likely missing a quote or comma somewhere.

Comment: Why would you want to use dynamic SQL here? The table and column names appear to be static?

Comment: I can not Print @CMD, I try to do this but no result.

Answer (score 0):

you have a few missing quotes, this is what your @cmd returns:

```
INSERT INTO MAG_Magasin
           (MAG_Magasin.NumMag
           , MAG_Magasin.Surface
           , MAG_Magasin.Lieu
           , MAG_Magasin.Adresse
           , MAG_Magasin.CodePostal
           , MAG_Magasin.IDTCommune
           , MAG_Magasin.IDTPays
           , MAG_Magasin.Ville
           , MAG_Magasin.IdEnseigne
           , MAG_Magasin.LibMagasin
           , MAG_Magasin.TelStandard
           , MAG_Magasin.IdClient
           , MAG_Magasin.DateCreation
           , MAG_Magasin.AcrCreateur)
       VALUES ('234',245,'Lieu','Adresse','78120','45,33,Ville',42,'LibMagasin','0123456789',452,Jan  1 1900  3:08PM','acr   )
```

it seems that @CMD should be like this:

```
SET @CMD='INSERT INTO MAG_Magasin
           (MAG_Magasin.NumMag
           , MAG_Magasin.Surface
           , MAG_Magasin.Lieu
           , MAG_Magasin.Adresse
           , MAG_Magasin.CodePostal
           , MAG_Magasin.IDTCommune
           , MAG_Magasin.IDTPays
           , MAG_Magasin.Ville
           , MAG_Magasin.IdEnseigne
           , MAG_Magasin.LibMagasin
           , MAG_Magasin.TelStandard
           , MAG_Magasin.IdClient
           , MAG_Magasin.DateCreation
           , MAG_Magasin.AcrCreateur)
       VALUES ('''+
            @Code + ''',' +
            CAST(@Surface AS VARCHAR) + ','''+
            @Lieu + ''','''+
            @Adresse + ''','''+
            @CodePostal + ''','+              
            CAST(@IDTCommune AS VARCHAR) + ','+
            CAST(@IDTPays AS VARCHAR) + ','''+ 
            @Ville + ''','+
            CAST(@IdEnseigne AS VARCHAR) + ','''+
            @LibMagasin + ''','''+
            @TelStandard + ''','+
            CAST(@IdClient AS VARCHAR) + ','''+
            CAST(@DateCreation AS VARCHAR) + ''','''+
            @AcrCreateur +
            ''')'
```